# isotope reLayout after animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to animate an element to a new height and width and then have isotope reLayout all the elements.  There's a demo for this and I'm trying to modify it.  It almost works, the animation happens but no adjustments are made, and then if you click any element a second time adjustments are made.  I'd like the adjustments to be made after the animation.

Here is my code and demo of what I'm trying:  http://jsbin.com/ifojiw/5/edit

JS:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');


  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element',
    masonry : {
      columnWidth : 120
    }
  });


  // change size of clicked element

  $container.delegate( '.element', 'click', function(){
    $(this).animate({
  "width": 400,
  "height":300
}, 200 );

    $container.isotope('reLayout');
  });



});
```

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the complete: option for animate to start the reLayout.

```
$(this).animate({
  "width": 400,
  "height":300
}, { 
  duration: 200, 
  complete: function(){ $container.isotope('reLayout'); }
});
```